# How to use Ionic Storage in Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a project built with Ionic v1 and Angular 1.x. I know how to use Ionic Native, I have installed the npm package and referenced the script file. Based on the guidelines from Github, you can get the service providers like **$cordova[plugin-name]**. So Camera would be **$cordovaCamera**.

I'm using **angular-local-storage** for storing JSON data but it's not entirely reliable because the OS can decide to clear it out when low on space. So I need a better solution like ionic-storage which uses SQLite for JSON and key/value storage. How do I use this plugin in Angular 1.x?

I have tried installing the plugin but can't get the provider available in my controllers/services.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Answer (score 0):

I'm involved in an Ionic v1 project now, and I personally recommend you `cordova-sqlite-storage` plugin.

As you know, **localstorage** is vulnerable to lack of memory in iOS although Android goes so so with it, thus it's not stable to depend on it for important app logic.

If you build your working into native apps, then [`cordova-sqlite-storage`](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#quick-installation) plugin will be a solution.

**config.xml**

```
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rob but I don't want to work with my data using SQL queries, it only complicates things and I'll need to refactor everything. I just need to store JSON objects or key/value pairs. LocalStorage works fine on both Android and iOS, but as we both mentioned, it's not entirely reliable.

Comment: You have the point. In the case of using **localstorage**, you'll meet some unpleasant things due to iOS clearing. It was really a headache for the some time, I remember.

Comment: Oh no, it's working fine on my iPhone 8 but this app is already in production and I can't afford to get negative user feedback. That's why I'm looking for a way to use the Ionic Storage module, because it uses SQLite and supports storing JSON objects. I'll see if I can find a quick and easy solution, I'll update this post.